# save checkbox in php but returned incorrect

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Maybe my question is familiar in this forum and my code more or less similar with many answer in here

i have a table with the data like this :

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form name="test_form" method="post" action="<?= base_url().'save_time'; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Save"/>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"/></th>
        <th>Day<br></th>
        <th>Opening Time</th>
        <th>Closing Time</th>
        <th>Full Day<br></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="1"/></td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="0"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="2" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="1" checked="checked"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="3" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="1" checked="checked"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="4" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="1" checked="checked"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="5" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="1" checked="checked"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="6" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="1" checked="checked"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cekday[]" value="7" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>Sunday</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open_time[]" value="03:00:00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close_time[]" value="22:00:00"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="full_day[]" value="0"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

or in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4z2uh1d/)

then i want to save data with condition :

1. if cekday is clicked then opening_time and close_time must filled
2. if cekday is clicked and full_day is clicked too then opening_time and close_time fill with null value

my controller :

```
public function save_time() {
    $detail = array();
    $numcheck = count($this->input->post('cekday'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numcheck; $i++) {
        $day = $this->input->post('cekday');

        if(isset($day[$i])) {
            $open_time = $this->input->post('opening_time');
            $close_time = $this->input->post('closing_time');
            $full = $this->input->post('full_day');

            $detail[] = array(
                        'day'           => $day[$i],
                        'opening_time'  => isset($full[$i]) ? $open_time[$i] : null,
                        'closing_time'  => isset($full[$i]) ? $close_time[$i] : null,
                        'full_day'      => isset($full[$i]) ? '1' : '0'
                    );  
        }   
    }
}

var_dump($detail);
```

but when i checked the result is not accordance as my expectation :

```
Array 
(
[day] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 6
        [5] => 7
    )

[opening_time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 3:00
        [2] => 3:00
        [3] => 3:00
        [4] => 3:00
        [5] => 3:00
        [6] => 3:00
    )

[closing_time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 22:00
    )

[full_day] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 1
    )

)
```

finally i want to save data using insert_batch,
thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: A unticked checkbox isn't included in the post data, you're using an array notation, I expect your index to get out of alignment. try adding your row index to the notation eg `<input type="checkbox" name="full_day[5]" value="1" checked="checked"/>`

Comment: Please remove the Java tag

Comment: thanks @Scuzzy, yeah the problem is about alignment index of array, i already revised my code and it works

Comment: Can I suggest you use this notation to group your field data better: `row[1][cekday]` `row[1][open_time]` `row[1][close_time]` `row[1][full_day]`, This will negate your need to re-align the array into $detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the above mentioned output, you have to do the below changes in code.

1) First you have to specify id's for all your html input elements to validate these before save.

2)On form submit you have to check for all the form validations.
onnsubmit="return savevalidate()"   --- append this in form tag.

```
//javascript function
    function savevalidate(){
        if($('#cekday1').is(":checked") == true){
        // do your other validations
    }
    else 
    return false;
    }
```

similarly other validations too.

Comment: the problem is solved, i adding row index as key in my input checkbox, thanks for the answer